# Downgrading java/gradle version homebrew

Tags: java, macos, homebrew

How would I go about downgrading Java from `15.0.2 to 1.8.0_261` and gradle from `6.8.2 to 5.6.4`? I currently have both of them installed on my mac and need to downgrade. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do this. However, there are tools that help you manage multiple versions of the same package on your computer. Gradle themselves, for instance, recommend "SDKMAN!" which i am using now.

[SDKMAN! link](https://sdkman.io)

it will be easier to work with it on Linux/MacOS than windows.